List overrides previous structures in list
I am trying to make an IT ticket system which allows for a user to input the name, the email, the date, the priority of the issue, and the issue description. It then allows the user to either add another ticket or print all tickets in order of priority. Currently, if I put in the information for one ticket it prints just fine. However, if I add more tickets, it will override all the data in the previous ticket with the new ticket's data with the exception of priority which will stay the same and be ordered correctly.
I have shown this code to my professor and we did some trouble shooting with it We believe that the problem resides in the function createTicket though it could also be a problem with printList. I want my code to create seperate data for each individual ticket and print them all in the correct order

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ticket {
    
    char *name;
    char *email;
    char *date;
    int priority;
    char *issue_description;
    int is_closed;
    char *issue_solution;
    struct ticket* next; //pointer to the next ticket
    
}Ticket;

Ticket* createTicket() {
    Ticket* newTicket = (Ticket*)malloc(sizeof(Ticket)); // Allocate memory
    if (newTicket == NULL) { // Check for memory allocation failure
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    char email[120];
    char name [120];
    char date [480];
    char issue [480];
    int num = 0;
    //name
    printf("What's the name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    newTicket->name = name;
    
    //email
    printf("What's the email: ");
    scanf("%s", &email);
    newTicket->email = email;
    //date
    printf("What's the date: ");
    scanf("%s", &date);
    newTicket->date = date;
    
    
    //priority
    
    while (num > 5 || num < 1){
        printf("What's the priority of the issue (1-5): ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(num > 5 || num < 1){
            printf("Invalid input. Enter a number between 1 and 5\n");
        } else {
            newTicket->priority = num;
        }
        
    }
    
    //issue description
    
    printf("What's the issue? (maximum characters: 120): ");
    scanf("%s", &issue);
    newTicket->issue_description = issue;
    
    
    newTicket->is_closed = 0;
    newTicket->issue_solution = "None";
    newTicket->next = NULL; // Initialize next pointer to NULL
    return newTicket;
}

void addTicketAtEnd(Ticket** head, Ticket* newTicket) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = newTicket; // If list is empty, the new node becomes the head
        return;
    }
    Ticket* temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newTicket; // Link the last node to the new node
}
// Print the list
void printList(Ticket* head) {
    
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("The list is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Ticket List:\n");
    Ticket* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
        printf("Email: %s\n", temp->email);
        printf("Date: %s\n", temp->date);
        printf("Priority: %d\n", temp->priority);
        printf("Issue: %s\n", temp->issue_description);
        printf("Solution: %s\n", temp->issue_solution);
        
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


Ticket* insertTicket(Ticket* head) {
    Ticket* newTicket = createTicket();
    Ticket* temp = head;
    //if newticket priority >= temp priority then set next and prev and change prev of next to current and change next of prev to current
    if(head == NULL){  //if list is empty
        return newTicket;
    }
    //if the priority of the head is less than the new ticket, set the newticket as the head
    if (head->priority <= newTicket->priority){
        newTicket->next = head; // Point the new ticket to the current head
        return newTicket;
    } else {
        while(1){
            if (temp->next == NULL){
                addTicketAtEnd(&head, newTicket);
                //temp->next == newTicket;
                //printf("Null");
                return head;
            }else if(temp->next->priority <= newTicket->priority){ //if temp priority is less than new
                //printf("2nd");
                newTicket->next = temp->next; 
                temp->next = newTicket;
                return head;
            } else if (temp->priority > newTicket->priority){ //if temp priority is greater than new,
                //printf("No result");
                temp = temp->next; //get the next element
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    Ticket ticket;
    Ticket* head = NULL;
    int option = 1; //1 to add a ticket, 2 to check off a ticket, 3 to print all tickets, 4 to exit
    
    while (1){
        if (option == 1){
            head = insertTicket(head);
        } else if (option == 2) {
            //check off a ticket
        } else if (option == 3){
            printList(head);
        } else if (option == 4){
            break;
        }
        while (1){
            printf("Enter a value between 1-4. 1. Add a ticket. 2. resolve a ticket. 3. print all tickets. 4. Exit: ");
            scanf("%d", &option);
            if(option > 4 || option < 1){
                printf("Invalid input. Enter a number between 1 and 5\n");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
   
   
    Ticket* temp;
    while (head != NULL) {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0; 
    
}



You don't need the ampersand in scanf("%s", &name);,. Also, name, ticket and all your arrays  goes out of scope when you exit the function, in consequence all members are pointers to garbage after createTicket (use strdup if available)

You shouldn't be using scanf to read directly from the user here. It just becomes cumbersome when you realize that people have spaces in their names and also that the issues they file most likely will have spaces. scanf("%s", ... will just read a word. See fgets instead

Another serious issue: createTicket stores the information in local variables. When the function returns, those variables are gone so the pointers will be "dangling" pointers that you are not allowed to dereference. You need to malloc space for them or make Ticket contain space enough: char name[120]; for example.

Testing out your code with the addition of some "printf" statements to do some simple debugging revealed that the main issue was that your ticket structure was using pointers to character arrays (strings) in lieu of defining character arrays of a specific size.  With that and the subsequent population of entered string information basically was providing undefined behavior within each ticket structure as to what memory position was being referenced for the strings.  Often the same memory location was being referenced within the "scanf" statements for string entry thus making it look like multiple tickets had the same data as the last entry set.
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/TicketList/bin/Release$ ./TicketList 
What's the name: Craig
What's the email: c@email.com
What's the date: 11/25/24
What's the priority of the issue (1-5): 1
What's the issue? (maximum characters: 120): Dunno
Enter a value between 1-4. 1. Add a ticket. 2. resolve a ticket. 3. print all tickets. 4. Exit: 1
What's the name: Lily
What's the email: l@email.com
What's the date: 11/24/24
What's the priority of the issue (1-5): 1
What's the issue? (maximum characters: 120): Ditto
Enter a value between 1-4. 1. Add a ticket. 2. resolve a ticket. 3. print all tickets. 4. Exit: 3
Ticket List:
Name: Lily
Email: l@email.com
Date: 11/24/24
Priority: 1
Issue: Ditto
Solution: None
Name: Lily
Email: l@email.com
Date: 11/24/24
Priority: 1
Issue: Ditto
Solution: None

Pointers do have their place within structure definitions, but with what your program is attempting to do with string information, it is much safer to define character arrays within your structure and also utilize string functions within your code.
With that in mind, following is a refactored version of your program that includes the "string.h" include reference and character array definitions within the ticket structure.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ticket
{
    char name[120];                 /* Assign a specific size to the various character arrays   */
    char email[120];
    char date[480];
    int priority;
    char issue_description[480];
    int is_closed;
    char issue_solution[480];
    struct ticket* next; //pointer to the next ticket

} Ticket;

Ticket* createTicket()
{
    Ticket* newTicket = (Ticket*)malloc(sizeof(Ticket)); // Allocate memory
    if (newTicket == NULL)   // Check for memory allocation failure
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char email[120];
    char name [120];
    char date [480];
    char issue [480];
    int num = 0;
    //name
    printf("What's the name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    strcpy(newTicket->name, name);
    //newTicket->name = name;

    //email
    printf("What's the email: ");
    scanf("%s", email);
    strcpy(newTicket->email, email);
    //newTicket->email = email;
    //date
    printf("What's the date: ");
    scanf("%s", date);
    strcpy(newTicket->date, date);
    //newTicket->date = date;


    //priority

    while (num > 5 || num < 1)
    {
        printf("What's the priority of the issue (1-5): ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(num > 5 || num < 1)
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Enter a number between 1 and 5\n");
        }
        else
        {
            newTicket->priority = num;
        }

    }

    //issue description

    printf("What's the issue? (maximum characters: 120): ");
    scanf("%s", issue);
    strcpy(newTicket->issue_description, issue);
    //newTicket->issue_description = issue;


    newTicket->is_closed = 0;
    strcpy(newTicket->issue_solution, "None");
    //newTicket->issue_solution = "None";
    newTicket->next = NULL; // Initialize next pointer to NULL
    return newTicket;
}

void addTicketAtEnd(Ticket* head, Ticket* newTicket)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newTicket; // If list is empty, the new node becomes the head
        return;
    }
    Ticket* temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newTicket; // Link the last node to the new node
}
// Print the list
void printList(Ticket* head)
{

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Ticket List:\n");
    Ticket* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
        printf("Email: %s\n", temp->email);
        printf("Date: %s\n", temp->date);
        printf("Priority: %d\n", temp->priority);
        printf("Issue: %s\n", temp->issue_description);
        printf("Solution: %s\n", temp->issue_solution);
        printf("Next ticket address: %p\n", temp->next);    /* Used as a simple debug  output   */

        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


Ticket* insertTicket(Ticket* head)
{
    Ticket* newTicket = createTicket();
    Ticket* temp = head;
    //if newticket priority >= temp priority then set next and prev and change prev of next to current and change next of prev to current
    if(head == NULL)   //if list is empty
    {
        printf("First ticket %p\n", newTicket);             /* Used as a simple debug  output   */
        return newTicket;
    }
    //if the priority of the head is less than the new ticket, set the newticket as the head
    if (head->priority <= newTicket->priority)
    {
        newTicket->next = head; // Point the new ticket to the current head
        printf("Same priority %p and new ticket address is %p\n", head, newTicket); /* Used as a simple debug  output   */
        return newTicket;
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            if (temp->next == NULL)
            {
                addTicketAtEnd(head, newTicket);
                //temp->next == newTicket;
                //printf("Null");
                return head;
            }
            else if(temp->next->priority <= newTicket->priority)   //if temp priority is less than new
            {
                //printf("2nd");
                newTicket->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = newTicket;
                return head;
            }
            else if (temp->priority > newTicket->priority)    //if temp priority is greater than new,
            {
                //printf("No result");
                temp = temp->next; //get the next element
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Ticket ticket;
    Ticket* head = NULL;
    int option = 1; //1 to add a ticket, 2 to check off a ticket, 3 to print all tickets, 4 to exit

    while (1)
    {
        if (option == 1)
        {
            head = insertTicket(head);
        }
        else if (option == 2)
        {
            //check off a ticket
        }
        else if (option == 3)
        {
            printList(head);
        }
        else if (option == 4)
        {
            break;
        }
        while (1)
        {
            printf("Enter a value between 1-4. 1. Add a ticket. 2. resolve a ticket. 3. print all tickets. 4. Exit: ");
            scanf("%d", &option);
            if(option > 4 || option < 1)
            {
                printf("Invalid input. Enter a number between 1 and 5\n");
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Ticket* temp;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;

}

Utilizing functions like "strcpy" ensures that unpredictable pointer references aren't occurring.  With those bits of refactoring, following is a sample of the output at the terminal utilizing the same two sets of ticket information.
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/TicketList/bin/Release$ ./TicketList 
What's the name: Craig
What's the email: c@email.com
What's the date: 11/26/24
What's the priority of the issue (1-5): 1
What's the issue? (maximum characters: 120): Dunno
First ticket 0x5652228f52a0
Enter a value between 1-4. 1. Add a ticket. 2. resolve a ticket. 3. print all tickets. 4. Exit: 1
What's the name: Lily
What's the email: l@email.com
What's the date: 11/25/24
What's the priority of the issue (1-5): 1
What's the issue? (maximum characters: 120): Ditto
Same priority 0x5652228f52a0 and new ticket address is 0x5652228f6170
Enter a value between 1-4. 1. Add a ticket. 2. resolve a ticket. 3. print all tickets. 4. Exit: 3
Ticket List:
Name: Lily
Email: l@email.com
Date: 11/25/24
Priority: 1
Issue: Ditto
Solution: None
Next ticket address: 0x5652228f52a0
Name: Craig
Email: c@email.com
Date: 11/26/24
Priority: 1
Issue: Dunno
Solution: None
Next ticket address: (nil)
Enter a value between 1-4. 1. Add a ticket. 2. resolve a ticket. 3. print all tickets. 4. Exit: 4

The takeaways from this bit of refactoring is possibly delve more into the use of pointers within structures via tutorials along with the utilization of standard string functions within the standard "string.h" definition.

What sort of date requires 480 bytes?  I suppose “In the seventeenth year of the reign of King Abemalluk, the thirteenth year after the disaster at the Falls of Binwallah, in the month of Goshemsten, and the nineteenth day thereof” might start getting closer, but even so….  32 bytes is likely to be (more than) enough.  I suppose my question is really aimed at @GriffinZee.

Thanks so much for the help. That worked exactly like I need it to!!

In addition to the problem already identified where you are storing several pointers to the same memory, thus seeing unexpected output, it's not a great idea to mix your linked list logic with your records.

typedef struct ticket {    
    char *name;
    char *email;
    char *date;
    int priority;
    char *issue_description;
    int is_closed;
    char *issue_solution;
    struct ticket* next; //pointer to the next ticket 
} Ticket;


Should really be more like the following, which separates the list logic from the record contents.
typedef struct Ticket
{
    char name[120];  
    char email[120];
    char date[480];
    int priority;
    char issue_description[480];
    int is_closed;
    char issue_solution[480];
} Ticket;

typedef struct TicketListNode {
    Ticket ticket;
    struct TicketListNode *next;
} TicketListNode;

typedef struct TicketList {
    TicketListNode *head;
} TicketList;

Other issues noted:

You should not be casting malloc. Should I cast the result of malloc (in C)?
Your createTicket function should not exit on a memory allocation failure but return NULL to the caller and let it decide how to handle that failure.
In insertTicket your if conditions all result in a return, so the else is extraneous and results in unnecessary indentation of the while loop it contains.
You're calling scanf without checking its return value to ensure success.
You're using scanf to read strings without a width specifier. This invites buffer overflow issues.
You're using scanf at all for reading strings rather than fgets which allows whitespace in input and makes it trivial to handle the buffer size issue.
You may wish to build a dynamically resizing array data structure rather than a linked list. See Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists


Thanks so much for your help. Your advice really helped me to understand the problem a lot better!
